# How Do I Get Inputs Value and Send to Mail Address?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone i had a problem and the problem is how to get values on inputs. I can get values with **console.log()**  but i don't want this. For example the person who visits my website, he wants to get more information about something and he wants to get in touch with me and he fills in the inputs. How can I get those inputs values and send them to my **email** address? Is it possible make it with **JS** if its not how can i solve this problem.

Those codes are for contact box.

```
<div class="box">
              <form>
                  <fieldset>
                      <legend> 
                          Bilgilendirme Formu
                      </legend>
                      <input type="text"  id="Ad" placeholder="Ad."  >
                      <br/>
                      <input type="text" id="Soyad" placeholder="Soyad."  >
                      <br/>
                      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail." >
                      <br/>
                      <input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Tel."  >
                      <br/>
                      <input type="button" class="button" id="Gonder" value="Gönder" onclick="getir()">
                  </fieldset>
              </form>

          </div>
```

Comment: You can use an event listener.

Comment: It's unclear what set of problems you're having. Are you asking how to send an email from your web app? There are many solutions for that, and likely OT for SO since it depends on your hosting and/or choosing an email provider. You get the form values the same way you do when you log them.

Comment: @DaveNewton 
First of all, thank you for your interest. I am designing a new website and there are inputs on the website that the user can give their contact information. The main problem is how do I send this data entered by the user from my own website to myself via e-mail. I hope I explained better than before.

Comment: @Mint 
Thanks sir I will look into it